# How can I optimise array multiplication by constant?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

Given the following code, where a, b, c, d etc are constants:

```
Data[] dataArray;
Intermediate[] interArray;
Output[] outputArray;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  interArray[i] = (c * dataArray[i]) + (a * dataArray[i+1]);
  interArray[i] -= (b * interArray[i - 1]) + (d * interArray[i - 2]);
  outputArray[i] = interArray[i];
}

for (int i = ln-1; i > 0; i--)
{
  interArray[i - 1] = (e * dataArray[i]) + (f * dataArray[i-1]);
  interArray[i - 1] -= (g * interArray[i]) + (h * interArray[i+1]);
  outputArray[i] += interArray[i]; 
}
```

How can I optimise this?

I want to walk the arrays only *once*. Unfortunately, I am dependant on the fact that the second loop requires the interArray to be filled by the first loop.

The reason I want to do this is because this process takes up 20% of my total running time, and I'm trying to optimise it. The arrays can be very large, and the types are usually large PODs. I'm assuming I'm stepping into cache trashing territory, which is why I'm trying to reduce the number of times I walk over the array. There is no * operator, it's just standard multiplication.

Notes : I am aware that the upper and lower boundaries of the arrays crash and burn here, due to going out of bounds. I would manually handle these.

Any advice would be appreciated! It's possible that I can't do it any faster, but I'd like to at least try!

Comment: Are you measuring this under release? - just to check.

Comment: You could try to use simd, or enable auto-vectorization in your compiler. But my guess is that you are already bottlenecked by memory bandwidth (a good profiler can tell you this). You could always try interleaving your values to possibly improve this somewhat.

Comment: @LogicStuff : Yes. I just had a thought - I think I can preemptively calculate the values that I will need, and do it in one shot?

Comment: `interArray[i]` depends on `interArray[i - 1]` and `interArray[i - 2]` so it's not easy to vectorize this

Comment: Speaking of the cache, it might help if your arrays aren't competing on the same cache line.   Read Sutter's piece about it (it's relevant to threading but might work here too): http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206

Comment: Those loops are simple to calculate an ideal cycle count. Compare with actual measurement to see if it's cache related or not. My guess is that your compiler is assuming pointer aliasing because of the absence of restrict keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will give you a huge time saving, but I think you can do the calcs in a single pass, by expanding out the terms. This could take it down to 6 multiplications and accumulations, as compared to 8 multiplications. Additionally you wouldn't need the intermediate array. It would look something like this (please double check the expansion of this)

```
Data[] dataArray;
Output[] outputArray;
auto DMinus2 = -c * d;
auto DMinus1 = -a - b*c;
auto D = c - a * b + f;
...

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    outputArray[i] = DMinus2 * dataArray[i-2] + 
        DMinus1[i-1] * dataArray[i-1] +
        D * dataArray[i] + ....
        DPlus3 + dataArray[i+3];
}
```

EDIT:

Firstly, apologies, my first answer is not totally correct. However, I am fairly confident that it is possible to simplify the loops.

For example, in the first loop

```
interArray[i] = (c * dataArray[i]) + (a * dataArray[i+1]);
interArray[i] -= (b * interArray[i - 1]) + (d * interArray[i - 2]);
outputArray[i] = interArray[i];
```

Can be simplified to

```
interArray[i] = (c * dataArray[i]) + (a * dataArray[i+1]) -
    (b * interArray[i - 1]) + (d * interArray[i - 2]);
outputArray[i] = interArray[i];
```

I am assuming that values outside the range are 0
Consider i = 0 then we have that

```
outputArray[0] = (c * dataArray[0]) + (a * dataArray[1]);
```

i = 1 gives

```
outputArray[1] = (c * dataArray[1]) + (a * dataArray[2]) - 
    b * outputArray[0];
```

i = 2 gives

```
outputArray[2] = (c * dataArray[2]) + (a * dataArray[3]) - 
    b * outputArray[1] - d * outputArray[0];
```

So, I think we can generalise the first loop to remove the intermediate array

```
outputArray[i] = (c * dataArray[i]) + (a * dataArray[i+1]) - 
    b * outputArray[i-1] - d * outputArray[i-2];
```

The same should also be true for the second loop. Having reviewed my maths again, I am not totally sure it is possible to combine the two loops. I'll keep thinking about this, as there may be a way to do it. Hopefully removing the intermediate storage should help.

Comment: This looks very interesting, but I honestly don't understand the maths behind it :( I'll try and figure it out and see if I can implement this.

Comment: can you elaborate how you came up with this?